# too many arguments for method apply: ()play.api.templates.HtmlFormat.Appendable in object list

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

File: `Controllers -> Product.scala`

```
    object Products extends Controller {
      def list = Action { implicit request =>
        val products = Product.findAll
        Ok(views.html.products.list(products))
```

throwing err

> too many 
>           arguments for method apply: ()play.api.templates.HtmlFormat.Appendable 
>            in object list

File: `views->products->list.scala.html`

```
     @(products: List[Product])(implicit lang: Lang)
     @main(Messages("application.name")) {
     <dl class="products">
```

File: `model->Product.scala`

```
     case class Product(                                     // MODEL CLASS
                ean: Long, name: String, description: String)
     object Product {                  // DAO :
      var products = Set(
       Product(5010255079763L, "Paperclips Large",
      "Large Plain Pack of 1000"),
       Product(5018206244666L, "Giant Paperclips",
      "Giant Plain 51mm 100 pack"),
       Product(5018306332812L, "Paperclip Giant Plain",
       "Giant Plain Pack of 10000"),
       Product(5018306312913L, "No Tear Paper Clip",
       "No Tear Extra Large Pack of 1000"),
      Product(5018206244611L, "Zebra Paperclips",
       "Zebra Length 28mm Assorted 150 Pack")
           )
           def findAll = products.toList.sortBy(_.ean)
```

File: `routes`

```
 GET     /products                       controllers.Products.list
```

its throwing error for too many arguments